# Issue with class variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am new to python.I was doing following code and I met an undesired outcome. Please look onto my code and let me know what am I doing wrong:

```
class TestClass(object):
  @classmethod
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val

  @classmethod
  def value(self):
    return self.val

def Test():
  a = TestClass(9)
  b = TestClass(8)
  c = TestClass(7)
  print(a.value(), b.value(), c.value())
```

expecting output as

```
9 8 7
```

but getting output as

```
7 7 7
```

what is wrong with my code.

Comment: `__init__` is a `@classmethod`???

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem good point! that's the answer BTW. A classmethod shouldn't be used, remove the decorators.

Comment: or maybe it's different in pythan.

Comment: if i remove @classmethod from __init__, it is giving error as "AttributeError: type object 'TestClass' has no attribute 'val'"

Comment: @Jai you should equally remove it from `value`, since `val` is now bound to the instance

Comment: @Moses, thanks. It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have attached `@classmethod` to the `__init__` function. As a result, if you call the `__init__` (something you do **at construction**), `self` will not reference to the object you are about to construct, but **to the `class`**, so `TestClass`. Therefore there is only **one `value`**: attached to `TestClass`.

So `TestClass(3)` will be equivalent to something like `TestClass.__init__(TestClass,3)`...

You can solve the issue by removing the `@classmethod` decorator:

```
class TestClass(object):

  def __init__(self, val): # no @classmethod
    self.val = val

  def value(self): # no @classmethod
    return self.val

def Test():
  a = TestClass(9)
  b = TestClass(8)
  c = TestClass(7)
  print(a.value(), b.value(), c.value())
```

It is actually rather weird to use a `@classmethod` on an `__init__` method. If you want to add attributes to the class, you can use `type(..)`. So:

```
@classmethod
def __init__(cls, val):
    cls.val = val
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def __init__(self, val):
    type(self).val = val
```

Answer (score 7):

Setting `__init__` as a `classmethod` means you're actually passing the class to `__init__` and `self.val` is actually set as a class variable, *not* an instance variable.

The final "initialization" you perform will override all the other values you've set.

Removing the `@classmethod`s fixes the issue.